# Spring Boot and GlassFish

Tags: spring-boot, glassfish

I actually have a spring boot application that i deployed on glassfish server 5.0 .
The probleme is that the jsp pages are not showing when i type the link.
I correctly configured the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CaisseApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(CaisseApplication.class, args);

    }
    }
```

the controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/imports_caisses_et_grandsLivres/")public class controller {

 @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String index(Map<Object, Object> model) {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

The jsp pages are correctly created, and to acces them, i'm using application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the brackets {} was missing in:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/imports_caisses_et_grandsLivres/"})
```